# Magento 2 error al guardar los atributos del cliente

Tags: magento2

Creo un módulo de cliente este módulo funciona bien, cuando migro datos de mangento 1.x a magento 2.x con la herramienta migración tool y deseo crear un nuevo cliente no guardar los datos tampoco muestra los datos cuando quiero editar un usuario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<?php


namespace mimodulo\CustomerAttribute\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute('customer', 'tipo_de_documento', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Tipo de Documento',
            'input' => 'text',
            'source' => '',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'position' => 333,
            'system' => false,
            'backend' => '',
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'tipo_de_documento')
            ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
                'adminhtml_customer',
                'adminhtml_checkout',
                'customer_account_create',
                'customer_account_edit',
            ]]);
        $attribute->save();

        $customerSetup->addAttribute('customer', 'telefono', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Telefono',
            'input' => 'text',
            'source' => '',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'position' => 333,
            'system' => false,
            'backend' => '',
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'telefono')
            ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
                'adminhtml_customer',
                'adminhtml_checkout',
                'customer_account_create',
                'customer_account_edit',
            ]]);
        $attribute->save();

        $customerSetup->addAttribute('customer', 'send_customer_points_notificat', [
            'type' => 'int',
            'label' => 'send Customer Points Notification ',
            'input' => 'boolean',
            'source' => '',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'position' => 333,
            'system' => false,
            'backend' => '',
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'send_customer_points_notificat')
            ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
                'adminhtml_customer',
                'adminhtml_checkout',
                'customer_account_create',
                'customer_account_edit',
            ]]);
        $attribute->save();

        $customerSetup->addAttribute('customer', 'notify_on_referral', [
            'type' => 'int',
            'label' => 'Notify on Referral',
            'input' => 'boolean',
            'source' => '',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'position' => 333,
            'system' => false,
            'backend' => '',
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'notify_on_referral')
            ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
                'adminhtml_customer',
                'adminhtml_checkout',
                'customer_account_create',
                'customer_account_edit',
            ]]);
        $attribute->save();

        $customerSetup->addAttribute('customer', 'especializacion', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'especializacion',
            'input' => 'text',
            'source' => '',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'position' => 333,
            'system' => false,
            'backend' => '',
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'especializacion')
            ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
                'adminhtml_customer',
                'adminhtml_checkout',
                'customer_account_create',
                'customer_account_edit',
            ]]);
        $attribute->save();

        $customerSetup->addAttribute('customer', 'departamento', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Departamento',
            'input' => 'text',
            'source' => '',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'position' => 333,
            'system' => false,
            'backend' => '',
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'departamento')
            ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
                'adminhtml_customer',
                'adminhtml_checkout',
                'customer_account_create',
                'customer_account_edit',
            ]]);
        $attribute->save();

        $customerSetup->addAttribute('customer', 'is_activated', [
            'type' => 'int',
            'label' => 'Is activated',
            'input' => 'boolean',
            'source' => '',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'position' => 333,
            'system' => false,
            'backend' => '',
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'is_activated')
            ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
                'adminhtml_customer',
                'adminhtml_checkout',
                'customer_account_create',
                'customer_account_edit',
            ]]);
        $attribute->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Daniel, necesitamos ver código, una imagen no nos dice gran cosa y menos con Magento 2 que es una aplicación relativamente compleja. No sé como esté hecho tu módulo, pero necesitaríamos ver el código que guarda (o que intenta guardar) y el que muestra el formulario (probablemente un xml).

Comment: Estos son los modulos que genero para el cliente, la parte de guardar los datos no se en que parte se encuetre

Comment: Comprendo, tratare de explicar mejor lo que me esta pasando el codigo principal del modulo seria la forma como se generan los nuevos atributos pues este lo desarrollecon base a un ejemplo.

Comment: Comprendo, tratare de explicar mejor lo que me esta pasando el codigo principal del modulo seria la forma como se generan los nuevos atributos pues este lo desarrolle con base a un ejemplo. funciona muy bien cuando lo instalo en un magento 2 en limpio, pero cuando hago la migracion del magento 1.x me generar errores con los atributos del cliente que adicione.
1. El backend listo los usuarios  y precio sobre el boton editar veo todos los datos.
2. Cuando guardo la informacion del cliente esta se borra y me genera un error por los atributos nuevos.
El metodo de guardado es el default.

Comment: Si el módulo funciona bien en M2, ¿para qué migrarlo desde M1? No entiendo esa parte.

Comment: El modulo funciona en mangento 2, cuando hablo de magento 1 es por que utilizo el modulo para la migracion de datos para pasar la informacion de magento1.x a magento 2.x que es donde se presenta el problema.

Comment: En ese caso el problema es de la herramienta que hace la migración, no de Magento.

Answer (score 0):

En el siguinte directorio
raiz/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/map-customer.xml.dist
creamos 
map-customer.xml

Creamos los campos que ignoramos

customer_entity.cedula

hacemos la migracion de datos

en magento 2 quitamos los datos que no deseamos

ejecución de consultas para borrar los datos
DELETE FROM `customer_entity_varchar` WHERE `attribute_id` in (attribute_id)
DELETE FROM `customer_entity_int` WHERE `attribute_id` in (attribute_id)

Despues borramos los atributos de la tabla principal

DELETE FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `attribute_id` in (attribute_id)